# Integrate irrational function

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I need to solve an indefinite integral
$$
I=\int\sqrt{x^4+2x^2-1}\,x\,dx.
$$
Substituting $x^2=t$ yields
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\int\sqrt{t^2+2t-1}\,dt=\frac{1}{2}\int\sqrt{t+1-\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{t+1+\sqrt{2}}\,dt.
$$
Now substituting $s=\sqrt{t+1-\sqrt{2}}\,$ yields
$$
I=\int\sqrt{s^2+2\sqrt{2}}\,s^2ds
$$
which opens way to solving the integral in hyperbolic functions, but it seems to me too much complicated. My question is: Is this the only way? Maybe there is something
else, not so complicated?

Comment: Not _so_ much of a difference, but $t^2+2t-1 = (t+1)^2-2$, so you could substitute $t+1 = \sqrt{2}\cosh u$, which may be a little nicer.

Comment: I would not be surprised if it is not doable by elementary functions.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\sqrt{x^4+2x^2-1}\,x\,dx$$

$$I=\int\sqrt{(x^2+1)^2-2}\,x\,dx$$

Let $u=x^2+1\implies x\,dx=\frac{du}{2}$

$$\frac12\int\sqrt{u^2-2}du$$

Doable now?

---

In case you are still stuck, proceed like so.

$u=\sqrt{2}\sec(\theta)\implies du=\sqrt{2}\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)d\theta$

$$\frac12\int \sqrt{2}\sec(\theta)\tan^2(\theta)\,d\theta$$

**EDIT**:Made a bad mistake here. Proceed through integration by parts.

Comment: Quite obviously, the answer cannot be a polynomial in $x$.

Comment: @user137208 quite obviously i screwed up something up. hold on. checking.

Comment: ah found. it's $sec(x)tan^2(x)$ not the other way round.